# How to make a simple webservice application in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I want to create a an webservice application in yii.As i am a new in yii so can someone suggest how can i do it.If i want to show google news in my application through webservice how can i do that?

Comment: Start by googling how to talk to Google News.

Comment: you must be look at this page [yii Web Service](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice)

Comment: Are you asking how to consume a webservice, or how to provide a webservice?  In any case, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a SOAP Web Service:

First add the [Web Service Action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebServiceAction/) to the controller you want to provide the service:

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'api'=>array(
            'class'=>'CWebServiceAction',
        ),
    );
}
```

Then you need to mark the functions in the controller that you wish to become services, with a custom PHPDoc `@soap`, and also define all of the params and return types of your service in the PHPDoc, so that Yii can generate the correct [WDSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL):

```
/**
 * @param string the module
 * @return string the version
 * @soap
 */
public function getVersion($module)
{
    //...find the corresponding version
    return $version; // ie: v0.1.3
}
```

Source : [Special Topics: Web Service](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice)

If you are looking for a REST service. then its a little more involved, as Yii doesn't have a built-in helper as it does for SOAP, but [jwerner](http://www.yiiframework.com/user/147/) [wrote a detailed wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api) on how to create a REST Api with Yii